# Mod Rewrite - Redirecting based on having GET parameters or not

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect these URLs:

`http://example.com/search` to `http://example.com/?page=search`

`http://example.com/search?q=keyword` to `http://example.com/?page=search&q=keyword`

I am trying to use this in **.htaccess** but doesn't work:

```
RewriteRule ^search$ ?page=search [nc]
RewriteRule ^search\?(.*)$ ?page=search&$1 [nc]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to direct the request to the index.php file include the file in the rules. E.g.

```
RewriteRule ^search$ index.php?page=search [L]
```

Give it a try.

Comment: Hi Andreas, it is working for the "/search" but not when adding parameters. Any ideas for passing the parameters?

Comment: RewriteRule ^search/([^/])+?$ index.php?page=search&q=$1 [L] (please try and let me know)

Comment: Thanks Andreas! I've replaced the `+` to `*` and moved the quantifiers inside the parenthesis and it works now. Here it is: `RewriteRule ^search/([^/]*?)$ index.php?page=search&q=$1 [L]`.